# Vector of void pointer to class template method

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, pointers, vector

im working on a DataManager, where Components can be registered, which creates a `Buffer<Component>`. This is working, but in order to save the buffers, I have a `std::vector<char*>`, since I can't save different types of Class Templates in the same vector.

```
        //register Components and return reference to them (Pre-Init Phase)
    template<class TComponent>
    ComponentID registerComponent(std::string Name = "",int ComponentNr = COMPONENTNR) {

        //Create Buffer<TComponent> with rising ID Counter
        ComponentContainer<TComponent>* t = new ComponentContainer<TComponent>(_componentIDCounter++, ComponentNr);

        //Add Buffer ptr to vector
        _container.push_back(reinterpret_cast<char*>(t));

        //return ComponentID
        return t->getComponentID();
    };
```

Now i want the DataManager to be a big wrapper class for creating and deleting components. For that i wanted to save a pointer to the createComponent methode of the newly created Buffer.
Problem is, i can either not define a vector for the given method...

```
typedef void (*CreatesPtr)(int);
...
CreatesPtr f = t->createComponent;
```

...which doesnt work, since it thinks i want to create a pointer to a member, not a method, or i could use **std::bind** to bind it since std::bind, but with that i can not define a vector for the function i want to call of every class template.

Maybe my way is just plain stupid and so much easier to implement some other way, so any suggestons are appreciated, but if there is a way to make this work i would definitly prefer that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting of with an unstated and incorrect assumption.

A class template can be derived from a non-template base class. You can store pointers to this base class in your vector.

The base class can have pure `virtual` methods, which you can call on the elements of your vector. The class template will implement these `virtual` methods, probably in terms of its template parameters.

In your case, it looks like `createComponent` would be the virtual method.

Comment: My Buffer<Component> isn't  a derived class, ComponentContainer<Component> is the derived class, which implements ComponentContainer::createComponent(int ID), by calling the Buffer::createObject(int ID). So if im not wrong, i can't make that function virtual.

Comment: @PSquall: My statement was to **make** `Buffer<Component>` a derived class, and to derive it from a new `BufferBase`. This serves only to define `virtual CreatesPtr BufferBase::createComponent(int) = 0`.